# How do I remove an attribute object with create var in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is There a way i ask user to enter a string, then I use the string to delete a property from object? like age, gender etc.

```
var person = {
  name: ['Bob', 'Smith'],
  age: 32,
  gender: 'male',
  interests: ['music', 'skiing'],
}
```

Comment: `delete person[string]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `delete` operator

```js
var person = {
  name: ['Bob', 'Smith'],
  age: 32,
  gender: 'male',
  interests: ['music', 'skiing'],
}

const propertyToDelete = prompt("Property to delete ?")

delete person[propertyToDelete]

console.log(person)
```

Comment: They said that the property name is a string given by the user, so you need to use dynamic property access.